# how can we access 2g internet in android application

Tags: android

i want to access 2g internet in my application to registered because some time net connection disconnect  .Please tell me how can access 2g network forcefully to bind the connection in my application

Comment: Simply select 2g only in your mobile device network connection. what is your problem to do this?

Comment: What if the device is running on Wifi? What if the device doesn't have a 2g/3g connection at all? What if the device has a good, stable, 3g connection? The user will be rightfully pissed with your application if you switch him to 2g. Handling a bad connection, and possibly changing it to a better one, is what the user should do depending on his environment, and not be attempted by an app.

Comment: my app working wifi and 3g good but problum in 2g network for registered on network